# Correct http error about missing or invalid field in json body

Tags: json, rest

My REST endpoint consumes json with some fields. What is the best http status error to notify user that some field is incorrect or missing?

I found info about *422 Unprocessable Entity* https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Is it what I need or you prefer another status error?

Comment: Please add a link to the site you're quoting.  That gives readers a way to judge how reliable the quote is.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the description you provide about the 422 Code, it sounds like it's exactly what you want.

> For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Replace `XML` with `JSON` in that sentence, and there's your answer!